# Convert VBA to a .NET language

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to convert VBA to C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388819/is-it-possible-to-convert-vba-to-c)

Suppose I have a big VBA project and want to convert it to a .NET language. Is there any way to do it automatically? Or maybe could I generate UML and a class structure, then append method bodies by hand?

Comment: No, [not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388819/is-it-possible-to-convert-vba-to-c).

Comment: Probably more effective use of time recoding the bits of VBA into a new project.  Keep things simple by sticking with VB .Net, but you'll find yourself replacing the ugly parts often enough to justify recoding.

Comment: Sorry, this is access forms project and I want any tool (preferably free) to convert it to a .net (C# or VB, doesn't matter) project. I'd also appreciate any ideas on generating UML from VBA.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a provided way to migrate VBA to .NET, but there are conversion tools online that might help as a syntactical reference for parts of the code. This approach will be cumbersome, but it might still be easier than doing it all by hand.

Here's an article that discusses migrating VBA to VB.NET:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192490%28v=office.11%29.aspx

**Converters**

Here's a VB.NET to C# converter:
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

And here's another one:
http://converter.telerik.com/

I don't know how helpful the converters will be since they're designed to convert .NET languages to other .NET languages, but seeing as how VBA and VB.NET do share some similarities, you might be able to use the converter for some of the code.

Comment: @JamesHill: Presumably because the first link is `VBA` to `VB.NET`, so it'd be `VBA->VB.NET->C#`

Comment: @JamesHill: I didn't say that they were the solution. I just said that they be useful for parts of the migration.

Comment: There are vb6->C# converters out there.  We used one at my former company.