# Generate uml from vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, uml

does anyone know a tool that generates UML diagrams from vba source code (preferably free)?
Thanks

Comment: Related to / possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228659/convert-vba-to-a-net-language

Answer (score 0):

This option looks like a good contender. While they don't do VBA specifically, they do VB (also VB.NET).

Since VBA is a scaled down version of VB, I assume it works. Also, it has a 30 day trial to meet your 'free' needs.

http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html